# Waiting for all mySql requests to finish before rendering page with express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I have a node.js server which queries a database after a user selects what types of lockers he wants to see the status of. A locker has various statuses : colonised, non_renewed, free, occupied. Obtaining any of these categories is done via a specific request.

What I would like is, if the user chooses all options, to be able to do all requests and put all rows into an array, then render a webpage with it. The problem is asynchrounous, ```connection.query```` does not return sequentially, and I do not know how to solve this.

```js
app.get('/admin/sites/lockers/*', function (req, res) {
    console.log("GET /admin/sites/lockers");
    let parsedQs = querystring.parse(url.parse(req.originalUrl).query);
    console.log(parsedQs);
    let resultArray = [];

    if(parsedQs['colonised']) {
        let query = fs.readFileSync('./sql/colonised_lockers.sql', 'utf8');
        connection.query(query, function (err, results, fields) {
            resultArray.push(results[0]);
            console.log("colonized :", resultArray);
        });
    }

    if(parsedQs['non_renewed']) {
        let query = fs.readFileSync('./sql/non_renewed_lockers.sql', 'utf8');
        connection.query(query, function (err, results, fields) {
            resultArray.push(results[0]);
            console.log("non_renewed :", resultArray);
        });
    }

    if(parsedQs['free']) {
        let query = fs.readFileSync('./sql/free_lockers.sql', 'utf8');
        connection.query(query, function (err, results, fields) {
            resultArray.push(results[0]);
            console.log("free :", resultArray);
        });
    }
    console.log("finally :", resultArray);
    res.render('admin/lockerView.ejs', {lockers : resultArray });
});
```

Comment: have you read about await and so on https://nodejs.dev/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find in the documentation of the tool you are using to connect to DB approach based on `Promise` rather then `callback`. But you can also wrap your `connection.query` into `Promise` and use `async` `await` in order to have "like sync" flow in the handler. Something like:

```
function makeDBQuery(query) {
  return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(query, function (err, result) {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

app.get('/admin/sites/lockers/*', async function (req, res) {
  console.log('GET /admin/sites/lockers');
  const parsedQs = querystring.parse(url.parse(req.originalUrl).query);
  console.log(parsedQs);
  const resultArray = [];

  if (parsedQs['colonised']) {
    const query = fs.readFileSync('./sql/colonised_lockers.sql', 'utf8');
    const result = await makeDBQuery(query);
    resultArray.push(result);
  }

  if (parsedQs['non_renewed']) {
    const query = fs.readFileSync('./sql/non_renewed_lockers.sql', 'utf8');
    const result = await makeDBQuery(query);
    resultArray.push(result);
  }

  if (parsedQs['free']) {
    const query = fs.readFileSync('./sql/free_lockers.sql', 'utf8');
    const result = await makeDBQuery(query);
    resultArray.push(result);
  }
  console.log('finally :', resultArray);
  res.render('admin/lockerView.ejs', { lockers: resultArray });
});
```

ofcourse you need some errors handler here and you can move repeated code into additional function but this is another story)